# Load css files in spring annotation

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security, jsp-tags

can any one help me to load css and image files in jsp.

I am getting this error while including css files : 404 (Not Found)

Here is the project code.

Jsp :

```
<link href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

This is annotation based spring application, so I am confused with loading css files.

Project example link for reference : http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-hibernate-annotation-example/

Comment: Post the generated HTML.

Comment: @chrylis You mean console log.

Comment: "link href="../assets/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="/spring-security-hibernate-annotation/assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="assets/plugins/uniform/css/uniform.default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/plugins/select2/select2.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/plugins/select2/select2-metronic.css"/>